# How to extend an extended content type on Plone

Tags: python, plone, content-type, archetypes, plone-4.x

I was investigating about addons and their schema extenders, interfaces, adapters, providers... but I cannot find out how to extend an extended schema. I'll explain my situation better:

I have three addons: L, H and V where L is the “base” addon. So H depends on L's content types because it's an extension of L. The content extensions was made using archetypes.schemaextender package.

Now I want to implement V, it should be an extension of H to achieve the following structure:

L → H → V

### Addon “L”:

This addon has a content type defined as class Batch(ATFolder). This addon also has its own schema and their interface marker IcontentA.

batch.py

```
class Batch(ATFolder):
    implements(IBatch)
    schema =....
```

interfaces.py

```
class IBatch(Interfaces)
```

### Addon “H”

This addon obtains the content class from L and extends it

batch.py

```
from archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces import IOrderableSchemaExtender

class BatchSchemaExtender(Object):
    adapts(IBatch)
    implements(IOrderableSchemaExtender)
```

configure.zcml

```
<adapter factory=".batch.BatchSchemaExtender " />
```

Ok, now I want to extend the content's schema with another addon. I've done something like:

### Addon “L”:

batch.py

```
class Batch(ATFolder):
    implements(IBatch)
    schema =....
```

interfaces.py

```
class IBatch(Interfaces)
```

### Addon “H”

batch.py

```
from archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces import IOrderableSchemaExtender

class BatchSchemaExtender(Object):
    adapts(IBatch)
    implements(IOrderableSchemaExtender,  IBatchH)
```

configure.zcml

```
<adapter factory=".batch.BatchSchemaExtender”
provides=”archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces.IOrderableSchemaExtender" />
```

interfaces.py

```
class IBatchH(Interface)
```

### Addon “V”:

batch.py

```
from archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces import IOrderableSchemaExtender

class BatchV(Object):
    adapts(IBatchH)
    implements(IOrderableSchemaExtender,  IbatchV)
```

interfaces.py

```
class IBatchV(Interface)
```

configure.zcml

```
<adapter
    for="L.interfaces.IBatch"
    provides="archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces.IOrderableSchemaExtender"
    factory=".batch.BatchV"
    />
```

As you are expecting it doesn't work... But I don't know if it's possible to extend an extended class.
I have to remark that each class has its own `init`, `getFields` and `getOrder` functions.
If I change the adapts definition on V addon I gets an error. Each function inside V addon has an `pdb.set_trace() definition, but the instance doesn't stops...

EDITED: 
I found in [this mail](http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/How-to-override-an-adapter-which-is-already-overridden-by-CMFPlone-td781690.html): "You can't override an override. Your only hope may be z3c.unconfigure:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.unconfigure
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registering multiple schemaextenders for a single content type should work as expected; I think your registration in V is incorrect.

in V, where you say

```
<adapter
    for="L.interfaces.IBatch"
    provides="archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces.IOrderableSchemaExtender"
    factory=".batch.BatchV"
/>
```

the corresponding class has the line:

adapts(IBatchH).

This could be

```
adapts(L.interfaces.IBatch)
```

If there are any configuration conflicts when Plone is starting, then you need to add a name="something_unique" to additional registrations to remove the conflicts.

Comment: imho you have to use named adapters, if you want to use multiple schemaextender adapters, otherwise you got a ConfigurationConflictError.

Comment: ahh just saw the second is more specific :-)